# How to show a map when finish a script, using Openlayers3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

I have got a script who do some things with a .txt local file. I open the raw text file from the local computer. Then the script reads some information inside the text file included some positions to render in a map. I need to render the map, using openlayer3, as son as the local text file is readen. How can I do this ? . There is a div (id='map') into my html file where I would like to render the map.

```
function() {

    var myVista = new ol.View({
   center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-30,40],'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'),
         zoom: 4,
    })

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [

            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }),  


        ],  
        view: myVista,
        controls: new ol.control.defaults({
            zoom: true,
            attribution: false,
        })
    }); 
    map.addControl(new ol.control.ZoomSlider());
};
```

That is my function to create the map.

In the end I try this:

```
    function traza_mapa() {
          var myVista = new ol.View({
   center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-30,40],'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'),
         zoom: 4,
    })

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [

            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }),  


        ],  
        view: myVista,
        controls: new ol.control.defaults({
            zoom: true,
            attribution: false,
        })
    }); 
    map.addControl(new ol.control.ZoomSlider());

    };
    traza_mapa();
```

It runs when I execute traza_mapa() in console but not into the script. I need to  run the traza_mapa() function into the script not calling from console

Comment: How are you loading this txt file? if it's jquery, you should have a callback that will fire when it's done loading, the map shouldn't load until you set it's target `map.setTarget('map')`

Comment: I can understand that